# Map an immutable List<Map<String, dynamic>> to other variable

Tags: dart

I am querying from an `sqlite` database and I get the result in a people variable that has the type `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` This variable is immutable and I can not operate on it. So I am trying to map this variable into another variable called `mPeople` which has the same data type. I am trying to do this in the following code.

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> people = [];
List<Map<String, dynamic>> mPeople = [];

Database db;
db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);
people = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM people");
mPeople = Map<String, dynamic>.from(people);

for(var i=0; i< firebaseIds.length; i++){
  mPeople.removeWhere((item) => item['id'] == firebaseIds[i]);
}
```

But I get an error saying `A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'.`. I don't understand why this is happening. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: If you check the API for `Map.from` it takes a `Map` as argument: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Map/Map.from.html and not a `List`.

Comment: @julemand101 Is there an equivalent of  `Map.from` for `Lists`

Comment: Yes yes give me a few minutes to make an example :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone it like this where you go though the list of maps and convert each map into a new map and then convert the result into a list:

```
mPeople = people.map((m) => Map.of(m)).toList();
```

But since you are going to use this list only for removing stuff later, it will be more efficient to just make sure this new list does not contain the elements you don't want. So you could properly make something like:

```
final mPeople = people
    .where((item) => !firebaseIds.contains(item['id']))
    .map((m) => Map.of(m))
    .toList();
```

Comment: The error is gone but it doesn't  remove the data with id equal to `firebaseIds`

Comment: What is the type of `firebaseIds`? It is rather difficult to help you without a full code example but I can suggest you try debug and see where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry it was because `firebaseIds` had a String. It worked once I parsed it to int.

Answer (score 0):

Turning immutable list to mutable in Flutter:

```
final mutableList = List.from(immutableList);
```